# Unable to render alpha when launching app on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11, ios12

I'm just learning Swift and with my first project I've encountered a strange behavior. When I run my app on iOS 13 in simulator, UIView successfully renders alpha for background view, but when I run it on iOS 12.4, I get black screen instead.

What am I doing wrong?

iOS13:
[Current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDocV.png)

iOS12: [What I get in simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p02bL.png)

To render it I do:

```
class ManualAddVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
...
var backdropView: UIView = {
    let bdView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
          bdView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
          return bdView
      }()
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(backdropView)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(backdropView)
....
}
```

Comment: Post the code you are using.

Comment: @Frankenstein, added

Comment: Why are you using `sendSubviewToBack`?

Comment: Because otherwise it overlaps the window with input fields. Commenting out didn't help much

Comment: Two thoughts? First, try setting the frame later in the view's life cycle. Maybe `viewDidLayoutSubviews` - and you really should be using both safe areas and constraints instead. Second, post a bit more code - enough for us to duplicate things.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving constraint instead of using `frame` and `UIScreen.main.bounds`:

```swift
backdropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    backdropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    backdropView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    backdropView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    backdropView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)])
```

Comment: didn't help much. Even tried not adding backdropView at all and got black screen instead of default View Controller background

Comment: Try quitting Xcode clear derived data clean the project and run again.

Comment: didn't help either